# MYSQL Query Takes 4 Hours

Tags: mysql, optimization

Good afternoon all.  I am coming to you in the hopes that you can provide some direction with a MYSQL optimization problem that I am having.  First, a few system specifications.

- MYSQL version: 5.2.47 CE
- WampServer v 2.2

Computer:

- Samsung QX410 (laptop)
- Windows 7
- Intel i5 (2.67 Ghz)
- 4GB RAM

I have two tables:

1. “Delta_Shares” contains stock trade data, and contains two columns of note.  “Ticker” is Varchar(45), “Date_Filed” is Date.  This table has about 3 million rows (all unique).  I have an index on this table “DeltaSharesTickerDateFiled” on (Ticker, Date_Filed).
2. “Stock_Data” contains two columns of note.  “Ticker” is Varchar(45), “Value_Date” is Date.  This table has about 19 million rows (all unique).  I have an index on this table “StockDataIndex” on (Ticker, Value_Date).

I am attempting to update the “Delta_Shares” table by looking up information from the Stock_Data table.  **The following query takes more than 4 hours to run.**

```
update delta_shares A, stock_data B
set A.price_at_file = B.stock_close
where A.ticker = B.ticker
    and A.date_filed = B.value_Date;
```

Is the excessive runtime the natural result of the large number of rows, poor index’ing, a bad machine, bad SQL writing, or all of the above?  Please let me know if any additional information would be useful (I am not overly familiar with MYSQL, though this issue has moved me significantly down the path of optimization).  I greatly appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

---

UPDATED with "EXPLAIN SELECT"

```
1(id)  SIMPLE(seltype)  A(table)   ALL(type)  DeltaSharesTickerDateFiled(possible_keys) ... 3038011(rows)   

1(id)  SIMPLE(seltype)  B(table)  ref(type)  StockDataIndex(possible_keys)  StockDataIndex(key)  52(key_len) 13ffeb2013.A.ticker,13ffeb2013.A.date_filed(ref) 1(rows)   Using where
```

---

UPDATED with table describes.
Stock_Data Table:

```
idstock_data    int(11)         NO  PRI     auto_increment
ticker          varchar(45)     YES MUL     
value_date      date            YES         
stock_close     decimal(10,2)   YES
```

Delta_Shares Table:

```
iddelta_shares          int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
cik                     int(11) YES MUL     
ticker              varchar(45) YES MUL     
date_filed_identify     int(11) YES         
Price_At_File       decimal(10,2)   YES         
delta_shares        int(11) YES         
date_filed                date  YES         
marketcomparable            varchar(45)      YES            
market_comparable_price     decimal(10,2)    YES            
industrycomparable          varchar(45)      YES            
industry_comparable_price   decimal(10,2)    YES
```

Index from Delta_Shares:

```
delta_shares    0   PRIMARY 1   iddelta_shares  A   3095057             BTREE       
delta_shares    1   DeltaIndex  1   cik A   18          YES BTREE       
delta_shares    1   DeltaIndex  2   date_filed_identify A   20633           YES BTREE       
delta_shares    1   DeltaSharesAllIndex 1   cik A   18          YES BTREE       
delta_shares    1   DeltaSharesAllIndex 2   ticker  A   619011          YES BTREE       
delta_shares    1   DeltaSharesAllIndex 3   date_filed_identify A   3095057         YES BTREE       
delta_shares    1   DeltaSharesTickerDateFiled  1   ticker  A   11813           YES BTREE       
delta_shares    1   DeltaSharesTickerDateFiled  2   date_filed  A   3095057         YES BTREE
```

Index from Stock_Data:

```
stock_data  0   PRIMARY 1   idstock_data    A   18683114                BTREE       
stock_data  1   StockDataIndex  1   ticker  A   14676           YES BTREE       
stock_data  1   StockDataIndex  2   value_date  A   18683114            YES BTREE
```

Comment: The problem is it could be any of these.  Could you run an explain plan?  What happens if you just try to update a few of the records?  How long does it take?

Comment: how long is the query `select * from delta_shares A, stock_data B where A.ticker = B.ticker and A.date_filed = B.value_Date;` taking?

Comment: Do the explain on the select statement that Sebas posted: explain select * from delta_shares A, stock_data B where A.ticker = B.ticker and A.date_filed = B.value_Date;   and post the results.

Comment: Updated the problem description with the "Explain Select" output.

Comment: I think I would use the resource monitor to watch how much memory is being used before the update is started, and during the update every 1/2 hour or so.  The datum to watch for here is to see if the machine runs out of usable memory and starts paging.   This will slow down processing significantly.   Also, your laptop hard drive is a bit slower than a dedicated database server would have.

Comment: :p the `... ` is probably the interesting one in the explain plan you added :-)

Comment: I wish.  I just skipped adding the blanks.

Comment: If it's a possibility try to create composite index (ticker, value_date, stock_close) on `stock_data` table, so that mysql can get everything it needs directly from the index. And make sure using `EXPLAIN` that it uses this index.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: engine=innodb ?? start transaction; update table...; commit;

Comment: Updated with additional information.  I appreciate the direction Andy, I was not aware there was a "Show Index" command.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few benchmarks you could make to see where the bottleneck is.  For example, try updating the field to a constant value and see how long it takes (obviously, you'll want to make a copy of the database to do this on).  Then try a select query that doesn't update, but just selects the values to be updated and the values they will be updated to.

Benchmarks like these will usually tell you whether you're wasting your time trying to optimize or whether there is much room for improvement.

As for the memory, here's a rough idea of what you're looking at:

varchar fields are 2 bytes plus actual length and datetime fields are 8 bytes.  So let's make an extremely liberal guess that your varchar fields in the Stock_Data table average around 42 bytes.  With the datetime field that adds up to 50 bytes per row.

50 bytes x 20 million rows = .93 gigabytes

So if this process is the only thing going on in your machine then I don't see memory as being an issue since you can easily fit all the data from both tables that the query is working with in memory at one time.  But if there are other things going on then it might be a factor.

Answer (score -1):

Try `analyse` on both tables and use `straight join` instead of the implicit join. Just a guess, but it sounds like a confused optimiser.